# iOS Movement of UISlider thumb to track the progress of the movie

Tags: ios, slider, uislider

I'm implementing a video player in which I've taken UISlider to track the progress of the movie. This would mean that the thumb of the slider should be at the max value when the movie finishes.

I'm not able to achieve this. Movie finishes before thumb reaches at the end. Could anybody please help me understand what could be the issue?

This is the code that I've written:

```
//I'm setting the min, max values of the UISlider and calculating the current value
progressBar.minimumValue = 0.0;
progressBar.maximumValue = (float)movie.duration;
progressBar.value = ((float)movie.currentPlaybackTime/(float)movie.duration) * progressBar.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: Why do you multiply with `progressBar.frame.size.width`?

Comment: Width of the progress bar would change when the device rotates to the landscape direction. Duration and current values of the movie would be the same. How will we map the progress in that case, I guess we'll have to consider the width of the progress bar. Please suggest what could be the better approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it just be: `progressBar.value = (float)movie.currentPlaybackTime` ?

I mean, lets say movie duration is 60 sec, and the movie is at 15 sec (this is `currentplaybacktime`, I guess).

so:

- progressbar min value is 0
- progressbar max is 60
- progressbar value should be between 0 and 60, and it is the value where the film is at right now: its 15.

Edit: You should also use: `- setValue:animated:`

Another idea: maybe you are not on the main thread. Make sure you are on the main thread when making ui changes.

Comment: I tried this as well but it doesn't work. Do you think it'll work correctly in both portrait and landscape mode? Progress bar would be longer in landscape mode.

Comment: See my edit:  try to use - setValue:animated: to set the value! But with progressbar.value, the frame's width is irrelevant. The value is between the minvalue and maxvalue, if it is min, it is on the furthest left side, if it is max, it is on the furthest right side (unless with arabic localization, i guess :)).

Comment: An other idea: maybe you are not on the main thread. Make sure you are on the main thread when making ui changes

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `progressBar.value = (float)movie.currentPlaybackTime;` instead of `progressBar.value = ((float)movie.currentPlaybackTime/(float)movie.duration) * progressBar.frame.size.width;`

Comment: This was the first thing that i had done, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Max value should be equal to the frame width:

```
progressBar.minimumValue = 0.0;
progressBar.maximumValue = progressBar.frame.size.width;
progressBar.value = ((float)movie.currentPlaybackTime/(float)movie.duration) * progressBar.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check and get back to you.

Comment: One of possible options, but why? Isn't it easier to stick to the duration of the movie (for the maximum value) instead of using the width of the control which will likely change on device rotation or any other layout change?

Comment: I think this is what he is trying to achieve; a slider that takes the full width and and shows the current position correctly.